# How to run spring-boot application using GitLab runner?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a spring-boot maven application I've been running locally as:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

I want to be able to run this in GitLab runner so that when I push the code to master, it automatically copies the latest up there and runs the application.

My GitLab runner is configured in shell mode right now, and I have inside of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file a deploy task that runs just that:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

The issue I am running into is after the application starts, I can see that it is running... but it never shows as success or completed. It just hangs there (because the terminal is still running when you execute that command?)

Question is, is there an alternate set of commands I should be running to get my spring-boot application to update and run each time I push to master? What is it i should be putting into my `gitlab-ci.yml` (or other files). Note that I am not using docker or kubernetes... just shell.

Sample gitlab CI:

```
run-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS spring-boot:run
```

Trying nohup with that also fails.
`- nohup mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS spring-boot:run &`

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit the issue? What is the expected result? Because when you run the spring boot application it is running continuously and you see that )

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to make it so that as soon as I push code into fit repo, it will auto deploy and start the app instead of GitLab runner being stuck.

Comment: Maybe better `repackage` jar by spring boot plugin and then run jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use the `run` stage for this. It would look something like

```
run:
  stage: run
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS spring-boot:run
```

You can see an example of this [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages).

Make sure you also define the `stages` to include `run` as the docs state

> If no `stages` are defined in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, then the `build`, `test` and `deploy` are allowed to be used as job’s stage by default. (see [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages))

Is the sample file you provided above your entire configuration file or only a snippet of it? If so, I can adjust my answer to fit your needs. Thanks!

Comment: but even if you do this, still job never ends, application starts and stays in runner. Did i do something wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry this is so late. I've recently just had the same problem. Gitlab runner blocks on child processes, and any process in the child tree. This makes the `disown` command impossible since you can't get to it. Forking, and `nohup` also don't work.

The only solution I could figure out was using the `at` command https://linux.die.net/man/1/at

Basically I put my command in a script then did:

`at now < my_blocking_command_script.sh`

That successfully complete the runner and kicked off my program in the background.